# Capybara should have_content is not waiting long enough

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, bdd

So I am writing an acceptance test using capybara. The scenario was to connect our newsletter system to external mail service.

We will get redirected to our external service page to request access to the external mail service. And we will be redirected back to our system page when succeed.

```rb
When "I grant authorization" do
  fill_in "username", :with => "myapp"
  fill_in "password", :with => "secret"
  click_button "Allow Access"
end

Then "I should see 'Connection Established'" do
  page.should have_content "Connection Established"
end

And "I should see that I'm connected to Sample External Service" do
  page.should have_content "Connection Established: Sample External Service"
  page.should have_content "Deactivate Sample External Service syncing"
end
```

But if I am not using `sleep` before the `page.should have_content "Connection Established"`. The spec will fail. From what I know, using sleep is not the best practice, because it will make our test run slow.

How to make it waiting until it got redirected back to our system

Answer (score 18):

There are 3 ways to adjust the maximum amount of time Capybaras methods will wait for their expectations to be true/elements to exist

`Capybara.default_max_wait_time = <seconds>` - This is the global setting which should be set high enough for the vast majority of your method calls

`Capybara.using_wait_time(<seconds>) do ... end` - This temporarily changes `default_max_wait_time` inside the block and then returns it to its original setting when done.  This makes sense when you have a number of methods you want to call with a new wait time, or you need to call a helper method with the wait time set to a different value.

`:wait` option - All Capybara finder and expectation methods accept a `:wait` option which will change the maximum wait time for that method call. This makes sense to use when you have a specific case that requires a bit more waiting than normal

```
# This will wait up to 10 seconds for the content to exist in the page
page.should have_content "Connection Established: Sample External Service", wait: 10
```

Note: In the future when posting questions it is generally helpful if you provide the full exact error message you get as part of your question.

Answer (score 3):

For page transitions, I like to wait for the URL to change first, and then wait for content on the page.  It gives you a more specific error if the redirect fails, and it naturally splits the long wait into two chunks.  With two opportunities to hit `default_max_wait_time`, the timeout is potentially doubled without actually changing it.  If it's still not enough, you can always pass a custom timeout into `have_current_path` with the `wait:` parameter.

```
expect(page).to have_current_path("externalservice.com")
expect(page).to have_content("Connection Established")
```

There might be a `page.should` equivalent, but I think the [official guidance](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/syntax-configuration) is to move to the `expect` syntax, since the `should` syntax was deprecated.

Comment: Like most other Capybara methods `have_current_path` can take a `:wait` option, to override the maximum wait for that matcher, so there is no need to increase `default_max_wait_time` just for one long duration redirect.

Comment: Hi thanks all, I will try this first and let you know the result

Comment: I have tried but it will work only when I add a `wait` option in have_current_path matcher

Answer (score 3):

You can use `capybara_watcher` gem, it is an elegant way of waiting for the `pege` to have a change in its content.
[Check it out on RubyGems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara_watcher)

Example:

```rb
wait_until_content_has "Connection Established" do |text|
  page.should have_content text
end
```

The perks of using this is that the sleep time is the actual time the page takes to have a change and you can configure it to exit after the second you choose if the page didn't change.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to similar problems:

```
module WaitUntil
  def wait_until(max_wait_time = Capybara.default_max_wait_time)
    Timeout.timeout(max_wait_time) do
      sleep(0.2) until yield
    end
  end
end
```

Using:

```
    wait_until { page.has_css?('li', text: 'test', visible: true) }
```

Comment: this is an interesting, appropriate, and flawed solution. It is flawed because the `has_css?` (or any `has_*` or any `find(...)`) ALREADY DOES WAIT. If you examine the code carefully, you'll notice yield is called inside an "until" loop, which is basically the opposite of a while loop. Theoretically it works, but what happens here is that because the `has_css?` is ALREADY waiting up to the capybara default wait timeout, it doesn't actually loop around the way you are expecting it to. Instead, it calls yield once, which waits the same length of time as Capybara.default_max_wait_time

Comment: so basically, you don't want to use a solution like this ALONG with any wait-aware Capy method. You could do something like this with success as long as you are using a non-waiting Capy finder (for example, by passing `wait: 0` in the finder itself). Then you are simply implementing your own wait helper. I typically do a similar solution with `page.evaluate_script(...)` which does a non-waiting script eval, and wraps that into a loop, and then basically am doing my own waiting for a non-standard thing.

Comment: @JasonFB, Yes, you're right, I found out about it a month after I wrote it. In fact, you can still use something like this: def wait_until(max_iterations); iterations = 0; until (yield || iterations ==max_iterations) { sleep(0.2); iterations += 1 }; end Or your solution, but it is also not always true, especially when using frameworks like angular.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Capybara.using_wait_time(seconds)](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/session.rb#L771) to temporarily change the value of `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` for special cases:

```
Capybara.using_wait_time(10) do 
  page.should have_content "Connection Established"
end
```