# How do I make assertions consistently wait until a turbo frame has been updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, hotwire-rails, turbo

My system tests are experiencing a race condition leading to inconsistent test results. Sometimes the turbo frame is updated before my assertion (test passes) and sometimes afterward (test fails).

View:

```html
<div data-controller="filter">
  <%= form_with url: root_path, method: :get, data: { turbo_frame: "intakes", filter_target: "form", action: "change->filter#submit" } do %>
      <%= select_tag "country", options_for_select(@countries) %>
  <% end %>

  <%= turbo_frame_tag "intakes" do %>
      <table>
        <% @family_intakes.each do |family_intake| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= family_intake.full_name %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </table>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This Stimulus controller submits my form on change event (ultimately updating the turbo frame):

```js
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["form"];

  submit(event) {
    this.formTarget.requestSubmit();
  }
}
```

Test:

```ruby
class FamilyIntakesTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test "Only intakes from selected country are displayed" do
    login
    select "Afghanistan", from: "country"
    assert_selector "td", text: family_intakes(:manizha).first
    assert_selector "td", text: family_intakes(:sayed).first
    refute_selector "td", text: family_intakes(:mohammad).first
  end
end
```

Error:

```
Failure:
FamilyIntakesTest#test_Only_intakes_from_selected_country_are_displayed [/home/eric/<redacted>/test/system/family_intakes_test.rb:31]:
expected not to find visible css "td" with text "Mohammad", found 1 match: "Mohammad Ahmad". Also found "Manizha Ahmadi", "Sayed Shinwari", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

Comment: You might be able use the `wait` argument with `should have_content` if you're using capybara, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55749877/7619578

Comment: What is on your page before selecting Afghanistan, and what is on it after? Are you sure you haven’t turned off capybaras waiting/retrying behavior?

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery I may end up going that route.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Before selecting Afghanistan, full names of all records are displayed. After, only names from records matching that country are displayed. In this case that's manizha and sayed but not mohammed.

Comment: I haven't really tweaked too many default settings. Capybara.predicates_wait is true.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My current solution is to add a `turbo-response` class to the table being updated inside my turbo frame and to scope my test assertions to that css class. That way I can't get a false negative if my assertion runs before before the frame is updated.

View update

```
<table class="<%= "turbo-response" if turbo_frame_request? %>">
```

Helper:

```rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def turbo_frame_request?
    request.headers["Turbo-Frame"]
  end
end
```

Test:

```rb
class FamilyIntakesTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test "Only intakes from selected country are displayed" do
    login
    select "Afghanistan", from: "country"
    within('.turbo-response') do
      assert_selector "td", text: family_intakes(:manizha).first
      assert_selector "td", text: family_intakes(:sayed).first
      refute_selector "td", text: family_intakes(:mohammad).first
    end
  end
end
```

Also, during the debugging process, to prevent any "accidental" success of my tests caused by the turbo frame just "happening" to load first, I intentionally slowed down my JavaScript form submission:

```js
submit(event) {
  setTimeout(() => this.formTarget.requestSubmit(), 1500);
}
```

The slowdown should be less than `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` which is typically 2 seconds or else Capybara really will give up. I went with 1.5 seconds or 1500 milliseconds. Just make sure to remove the `setTimout` later! Getting my tests to pass with or without that slowdown gives me way more confidence that they are passing for the right reasons!

Comment: This really shouldn't be necessary, although scoping is always a good idea to isolate changes.  You should check for the things that change on the page first in order to synchronize.  Since the change on the page is "mohammed" going away you should do the `refute_selector` first, which assuming your Capybara.default_max_wait_time is set large enough for the hardware you're running on will cause Capybara to wait for the entry to be removed from the page before moving on to your 'assert_selector' calls. I'd also recommend using `assert_css/refute_css` over xxx_selector when using a CSS locator